# React hooks - Can't use hook inside plain async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I'm new to hooks and have been mildly impressed thus far, however, it seems to complain if I try to use hooks inside a function (Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons).

I have several common API functions inside a base file which are used to retrieve data from the API. They do NOT return anything and merely dispatch (useDispatch) to the store and the associated components using this state are updated throughout the app. I understand that is probably the reason as it's not returning a React element, but is there a way around this or a better, more "recommended" React approach? It's not the end of the world if I have to manually pass in the user and dispatch on the returned result in the parent component, but I'd rather keep it in one place and handle it all in this function so all the parent component has to do is update when the state changes.

This is the function:

```
export async function getCar(id) {

  // It's complaining about these hooks
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  try {
      let response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}api/cars/getCar/${id}/${user.id});
      if (response.data.successCode === 200) dispatch(setCar(response.data));
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

USAGE:  `const carsList = getCar("id");`

Thanks all,
Much appreciated.

Comment: You need to have all the hooks in the body block of the function component. Cannot be used in other functions inside.

Comment: This is explained in the rules of hooks in the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook are different from function. Considering you want to implement a custom hook, you first need to prefix your hook name with `use`

Secondly hooks can't return async values unless you store it in state. Also you need to make use of useEffect function to make sure that the api request is only fired once or on change of id param.

```
export function useGetCar(id) {
  // It's complaining about these hooks
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
     async function myFn() {
        try {
              let response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}api/cars/getCar/${id}/${user.id});
              if (response.data.successCode === 200) dispatch(setCar(response.data));
        } catch (error) {

        }

      }
      fn()
  }, [id])
}
```

Also since you are just updating the state you could write another selector to get the car value from redux store

usage:

```
const Comp = ({id}) => {
    useGetCar(id);
    const car = useSelector(state => state.car);
}
```

Comment: Missing dependencies for effect: `dispatch` and `user.id`. You can add `dispatch` since that comes from react-redux and won't change but will quiet the linter. However; user.id is important because you may want to actually run the effect again when that changes.

Comment: @HMR, yes makes sense, you can add user.id along with id as a dependency to useEffect

Comment: Thank you for this. It really cleared up the use case of hooks for me! Just one more thing; how could you pass in a param after the hook is called? (So a didUpdate). I understand it would be useGetCar(id), but what if I wanted to do useGetCar() first to get all cars, then pass in an id on search?  You can't do onChange={value => useGetCar(value)} as it would break order of the hooks being called? Thank you

Comment: @user.io In such cases you have a couple of options, either you implement useGetCar such that if id passed is null you fetch all cars and when you want to get all cars by id, you update the id in state which gets passed on to the hook and gets data for you. The other solution is to expose a function from hook that you can call to get cars by Id

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamKhatri!! That's really cleared everything up. I'll pass in a state to the hook which'll trigger the update of the effect and fetch by id. That makes complete sense now. I really appreciate your help - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle features from function components. Hooks don’t work inside classes — they let you use React without classes.

You can not put hooks inside `if` statements, functions, loops and [they can't be nested in anything](https://youtu.be/O6P86uwfdR0?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH8EtggFGERCwMY5u5hOjf-h).

Hooks can only be called inside the top level of the body of a function component.

Read the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#but-what-is-a-hook).

Answer (score 0):

For the situations when you have a React app running allong with some legacy code or in a microfrontend architecture you could trigger render from plain javascript by using `useCallback` and a window event.

```
// in the hooks file
export const useForceUpdate = () => {
  const [, setTriggerUpdate] = useState(0);
  const update = useCallback(() => {
    setTriggerUpdate((tick) => tick + 1);
  }, []);
  return update;
};
```

```
const handleMyOutsideCall= (
  callback: () => void
) => {
  window.addEventListener("myEvent", (e: CustomEvent) => {
    const data = e.detail;
    callback(data);
  });
};


export const dispatchMyOutsideCall = (name: string) => {
  const event = new CustomEvent("myEvent", {
    detail: {
      name: name,
    },
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};

// import useForceUpdate from hooks file 
export function MyComponent() {
  const {data, setData} = React.useContext(SomeContext);

  const update = useForceUpdate();
  useEffect(() => {
    handleMyOutsideCall(update);
  }, []);

  return <>App</>
}
```

And then in some other es module outside react scope:

```
   // this will trigger state update on MyComponent
   dispatchMyOutsideCall("My_Test")
```

Hope it helps